# Index not getting created in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my code which Im using to index some data. But,when I search for the index,in elasticsearch it is not getting created there.

```
var createIndex = function(refId,docFeed){
    esClient.create({
        index:"indexName",
        type:"typeName",
        id:refId,
        body:docFeed    
    },
        function(error,response){
            emptyFunction();
    });
```

}

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Instead of emptyFunction use something else to print the error. Also check your cluster log for error messages. Post the error you see, it will make easy for users to identify the issue and help you better.

Answer (score 3):

> Index names are limited by the file system. They may only be lower
>   case, and my not start with an underscore. While we(elasticsearch)
>   don't prevent index names starting with a ., we(elasticsearch) reserve
>   those for internal use. Clearly, . and .. cannot be used.

[source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6736)

Change your code to

```js
var createIndex = function(refId, docFeed) {
    esClient.create({
        index: "indexname",
        type: "typename",
        id: refId,
        body: docFeed
      },
      function(error, response) {
        emptyFunction();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume the problem is with your index name. Elasticsearch doesnt allow,capital letters in index name and type creation.
So better try with index name and type names with lower case.